# W/OpenGLRenderer: Points are too far apart

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, computational-geometry, android-source

When constructing a vector that is an ellipse, I am getting this warning message in LogCat:

```
W/OpenGLRenderer: Points are too far apart 4.000000
```

I am interested in knowing what exactly this means.  I noticed in the AOSP that there is a drawArc Method that throws this warning, however, it does not give a clear representation of what exactly is meant. Do I need to adjust my vector drawables?  Will I see any future errors or drawing mistakes from these warnings?  How can I get these warnings to subside?

[AOSP Reference file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/17e64ffd852f8fe23b8e2e2ff1b62ee742af17a6/core/java/android/util/PathParser.java#417)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warning "Points are too far apart" means the "A" path command specifies an ellipse that's too small to form an arc between the endpoints. To handle this, the `drawArc` method enlarges the ellipse's size so that it can adequately form an arc between the endpoints.  To avoid the warning, you have to avoid such problematic "A" commands.

For example, the following path (specifying a 1x1 ellipse that's too small to go through the endpoints) will trigger this warning:

```
M10 10 A 1 1 0 1 1 5 5
```

While the following path (specifying a 10x10 ellipse with the same endpoints) will not:

```
M10 10 A 10 10 0 1 1 5 5
```

Comment: Is there anything one can do to resolve the warning?

Comment: As I mentioned, to avoid the warning you have to avoid "A" commands that specify ellipses that are too small to form an arc between the end points (note that the "A" command largely mirrors how that command works in SVG, the W3C's specification for Scalable Vector Graphics).  This warning occurs probably because Android and SVG viewers might render such problematic "A" commands differently

Comment: Okay, now I understand ... thanks for clarifying again :)